# Less file styles not applying in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, less, less-css, magento2minicart

I have  custom theme in ..../design/frontend/MyVendor/my-theme folder. My main less file is in design/frontend/MyVendor/my-theme/web/css/my-main.less.
Content of the main less file:

```
@import './source/_module.less';
```

Location of _module.less file is in the folder

```
design/frontend/MyVendor/my-theme/web/css/source/_module.less
```

Contents of _module.less:

```
@import 'module/_cart.less';
@import 'module/_minicart.less';
@import 'module/_checkout.less';
```

The way I include my main less file is in default_head_blocks.xml:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" src="css/my-main.less" />
    ......
```

The file is included, no errors anywhere, run the fallowing commands:

```
magento cache:flush
rm -rf pub/static
rm -rf var/cache
rm -rf var/page_cache
rm -rf var/view_processed
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

both

> magento cache:flush &  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

run without ANY errors.
Still, the changes I made in module/_minicart.less are no presented when I refresh the page. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The way I include my main less file is in default_head_blocks.xml:

```
<head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/my-main.less"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way I include a less file in default_head_blocks.xml is:

```
<head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/my-main.css"/>
</head>
```

Where *`css/my-main.css`* is actually *`css/my-main.less`*. It automatically transforms it somehow. So basicaly you use *`file-name.css`* in *`default_head_blocks.xml`* but you write your code in *`file-name.less`* file

Answer (score 0):

Rename your main less file to _extend.less from my-main.less.

Put it in below location

```
design/frontend/MyVendor/my-theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Insert your other less file in _extend.less, Like this

```
@import 'module/_cart.less';
@import 'module/_minicart.less';
@import 'module/_checkout.less';
```

FYI module directory should be `design/frontend/MyVendor/my-theme/web/css/source/module`